# HttpServer HttpRequest session creation

Tags: dart

Dart HttpServer.listen returns an HttpRequest. There is also a timeout associated with the server which controls how long the HttpRequest remains active. How does the HttpServer identify what has generated the request (for retrieval), and how does it store the requests, and why does it save them?

In the situation that I encountered, accessing the same server from different tabbed pages of the browser used the same server request. If different browsers were used however, it appears that different requests are created. Is it possible to force the server to create different requests for tabbed pages?

Comment: are you talking about request or did you mean session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your question mixes requests and sessions. If I misunderstood it, please ignore.

The timeout associated with the HttpServer (I assume you mean `HttpServer.sessionTimeout`) controls the lifetime of the session, not the request.

The sessions are based on cookies. The server writes session identifier into a cookie. This cookie is then used in communication between browser and server, so server checks the cookie, an gives you the appropriate session to use. This is a typical implementation, some frameworks allow storing the whole session in the cookie, but that has many drawbacks, I won't go into. Dart's `HttpSession` is just an in-memory map, which is internally mapped to the session cookie value.

Since browser tabs (at least for most of the browsers, I am not an expert on that) share the cookies, request done from any tab to the same domain will result in the same session being used. Naturally, another browser uses its own cookie store, so you have different session there.

This problem is sometimes solved by encoding the session ID in the URL (google for 'URL encoded session IDs' as implementations are specific for the chosen backend), but I don't see any supported way to plug that approach into `HttpServer` class. The session creation is implemented in `_HttpSessionManager` type which is private to `dart:io` library, and doesn't provide any public extension points, so you would most likely need to wrap your own support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have probably confused requests and sessions as you say. I have only just started looking at this because of work on a test program that I was doing (to become more familiar), and results that were unexpected (to me). The results are similar to eg. Gmail which initially surprised me using Gmail when accessing from another Tab. However, Yahoo Mail appears to act differently and creates a new session.

Comment: Well, yahoo mail does act differently (to Gmail), but does not create a new session for each tabbed page it appears.